# ImportError: works on osx not on ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ubuntu, importerror

I have a strange import problem with python. The same code works on OSX, but it doesn't work on precise 12.04.

```
test.py
lib/
   twitter/
     twitterstream.py
     __init__.py
```

The twitterstream.py has a class TwitterStream.

test.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./lib')
import twitter.twitterstream

tw = twitter.twitterstream.TwitterStream()
tweets = tw.fetchsamples()
print tweets
```

I am getting following error:

```
> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in 
    import twitter.twitterstream
ImportError: No module named twitterstream
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another module `twitter` installed on your Ubuntu machine.

You put the `./lib` path *at the end* of the module search path; the other `twitter` module is installed in a location listed on the `sys.path` search path before that.

Insert `./lib` at the start instead:

```
sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton !! Spent so much time debugging this.

Comment: How did you find out?

Comment: Experience and answering loads of questions. :-)